# Java Grayscale Images

Tags: java, performance, grayscale

I've been working towards grayscaling images in java for some time. I was using a `colorConvertOp`, but it seems after a load of images were put through the process, eventually the JVM would hang in a locked state in the op.

Now I've started using:

```
BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size, size, BufferedImage.TYPE_BYTE_GRAY);  
Graphics g = image.getGraphics();  
g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);  
g.dispose();
```

However, I'm seeing a large spike in CPU, where it used to be under **20%** and is now up to **120%**. It also seems to be causing me memory leaks and eventually *OOMs*.

Is there an easier, quicker way to grayscale in java without using as much CPU/eliminates hanging from a JVM bug?

Comment: How much time does it take?

Comment: Maybe... You're speaking about a bug, actually two of them. Can you show us a complete crashing example?

Comment: Memory leaks in Java. With a garbage collector that's quite impossible...

Comment: What is the size of the image, what is the original format,... It's hard to reproduce results if the data is not available.

Answer (score 0):

**I wrote a java program to convert RGB image to GrayScaleImage. Hope this helps**

```
public class GrayScale {

    BufferedImage image;
    int width;
    int height;

    public GrayScale() {

        try {
            File input = new File("input path of the image");
            image = ImageIO.read(input);
            width = image.getWidth();
            height = image.getHeight();

            for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) {

                for (int j = 0; j < width; j++) {

                    Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
                    int red = (int) (c.getRed() * 0.299);
                    int green = (int) (c.getGreen() * 0.587);
                    int blue = (int) (c.getBlue() * 0.114);
                    Color newColor = new Color(red + green + blue,

                    red + green + blue, red + green + blue);

                    image.setRGB(j, i, newColor.getRGB());
                }
            }

            File ouptut = new File("output path of the image");
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", ouptut);

        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    static public void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        GrayScale obj = new GrayScale();
    }

}
```